# Using arrays to find Temp

Tags: c#

How to use arrays in a loop correctly

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Temp t = new Temp( 100,52,98,30,11,54,87);
        Console.WriteLine(t.lowest());
    }
public class Temp
    {
        private int[] temp = new int[7]; // array 
        public Temp(int d1, int d2, int d3, int d4, int d5, int d6, int d7) // constructor with 7 parametors
        {

            temp[0] = d1; // assigning constuctor parametors to array
            temp[1] = d2;
            temp[2] = d3;
            temp[3] = d4;
            temp[4] = d5;
            temp[5] = d6;
            temp[6] = d7;

        }
        public int lowest() // returning the lowest value of the set of numbers
        {
            int smallest = 150;
            for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
            {
                if ( temp[c] < smallest)
                {
                    smallest = temp[c];
                }

            }
            return smallest;
```

Now my question is not to do my homework. But a question to find the highest temp and average.
Would I do another for loop with an intiatilzing `int highest = -1;` then do something close to what I did for the smallest?

Comment: sounds like a class assignment to me... what have you tried so far?

Comment: I think I'd do it by coding it as per the specs.  Show us some code, and we can help you fix it.

Comment: @zach, It appears to me you've added the phrase "how would you do this.." to your homework assignment.  This is not a "do my homework for me" site.  It is a "how do I solve this problem where I got stuck" site.

Comment: Well, step one is to write some code and see if it compiles and fulfils the 6 requirements. Step next is to post a short self contained example of your broken code on StackOverflow: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Kevin pun intended, I assume? (assignment for class and in the main method you need to assign the class to a variable)

Comment: @MatthewMartin, your edit did nothing to make this question more answerable and merely hid the fact it was a direct recapitulation of a homework assignment.  Unsalvageable at this point.

Comment: I guess stackoverflow is just Mechanical Turk (https://www.mturk.com/mturk/) now, but he hasn't even offered me $0.23 to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

**`find the highest temp?`**
Just change this condition `if ( temp[c] < smallest)` of your method `public int lowest()` to `if ( temp[c] > smallest)` , you will get the highest.
**`For Average?`**
You need to write a loop which add values of all indexes and then divide the sum by `7` or `temp.Length;`

I thought to provide you the sample code but I guess it is so easy and you should do it by yourself.The ideas I gave are enough